# Can I use Siri on Mac to trigger stuff on IFTTT?

Tags: mac, siri

I'm using IFTTT with Google Assistant on my Android and it works like a charm, I was wondering if anyone knows a way I could use Siri on my Mac along with IFTTT?

Comment: There's a ton of recipes on the IFTTT website that use Siri and other devices.  Have you looked there?  If so, what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering if anyone knows a way I could use Siri on my Mac along
>   with IFTTT

Assuming you are referencing "Mac" to mean a Mac *computer* and not a mobile device such as an iPhone, iPad, or iPod, then **no, you cannot use IFTT via Siri on your Mac.**

From the [App Store link of the IFTT website:](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ifttt/id660944635?mt=8?utm_medium=Help&utm_source=Basics&utm_campaign=Using_IFTTT&utm_term=&utm_content=)

> This app is only available on the App Store for iOS devices.

However, if you're using it on iOS there is support for Siri.  See this Knowledge Base article:  [Using Siri with the Note widget service](https://help.ifttt.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002284933-Using-Siri-with-the-Note-widget-service)